# Fragment return null in viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a main activity called GuivActivity that uses viewPager to switch between two fragments (listFragment and SearchFragment). But when I try to get Fragment by id inside onPageSelected, it returns null.

All I want to do here is to restart the loader in ListFragment so that every time when I come back I will have most updated data.

in GuivActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_guiv);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        indicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.titleindicator);
        pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        indicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
        indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(listener);
    }
   ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
       @Override
       public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

       }
       @Override
       public void onPageSelected(int position) {

           switch (position){
               case 0:
                   FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                   ListFragment listFragment = (ListFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.list_fragment_id);

               case 1:

               default:
                   break;
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

       }
   };
```

in ListFragment.java

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    Message.message(mContext,"on resumed called");
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LIST_LOADER,null,this);
    super.onResume();
}
```

in GuivActivity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/titleindicator"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

in the fragment adatper

```
 @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch(position){
        case 0:
            return new ListFragment();
        case 1:
            return new SearchFragment();
        default:
            break;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Use `FragmentPagerAdapter` and everything will be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

```
ListFragment listFragment = (ListFragment) pagerAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, position)
```

**Solution 2** It's a hack

```
ListFragment listFragment = (ListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
       "android:switcher:" + R.id.viewpager + ":" + viewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

**Note**
But I would suggest you to use `FragmentPagerAdapter`. It would give you much more control than `PageAdapter`

Comment: yes I got the listFragment, but can I like a method here directly? like listFragment.method1()  listFragment.onResume()?

Comment: I am using a pagerAdapter, both your solutions worked ! thank you!

Comment: Yes I think you can. But don't play with the lifecycle methods such as `onResume`

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Been trying to find a solution for a few evenings now, this is the only one that worked :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you call your fragment class to get the view? then call add on your fragment manager. It's a lot cleaner that way and easier to implement the "back" button.

```
public void displayView(int position, Bundle arguments) {

         Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new ListFragment();
                break;
            case 1:               
                break;          
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
            boolean fragmentPopped = fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate (backStateName, 0);

            if (!fragmentPopped&&fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(backStateName) == null){ //fragment not in back stack, create it.
                FragmentTransaction ft =fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment,backStateName);
                ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
                ft.commit();

            }

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            if (position==0){

            }
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not following you here.. what should be the R.id.frame_container? and what is the mDrawerList?

Comment: you can ignore the mDrawerList, i just used a snippet from my code where i drew my own menu. And the Frame Container is where the fragment resides. So add this to your main_activity.xml 

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: ok. are i supposed to use getSupportFragmentManager or getFragmentManager? I used your code it returns some compatibility issue

Comment: Use whatever works, i don t actually know the difference

Answer (score 0):

Coincidentially I was tackling the same problem today. They key is to instantiate the adapter like this:

```
  mAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);

      mCurrentFragment = (Fragment) object;
    }
  };
```

Now everytime the view pager switches to another fragment (even on first load and screen orientations) that fragment will be loaded into the `mCurrentFragment` field variable (don't forget to declare it).

**Pros:** You don't have to work with internal fragment ids. I just tested it. And it's quite elegant.

**Cons:** None that I know of.

**Note:** Also don't forget to implement `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` and `onViewStateRestored(Bundle)` in your paged fragments if you need that. *Based on true story.*